# Is there any way of creating a GIF from a square selected space on my screen?

Tags: command-line, scripts, software-recommendation, gif

I'd like to create a script that allows me to create a square on my screen and start creating a gif file after the square is made. I think about something like the following:

[image]

This last gif I've created using [Peek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peek_(software)) and the selected area I've used the command `gnome-screenshot --area`. They both won't do what I want and I've used them here just as an example.

Are there any command-line tools that I can put together in order to create something like this? In pseudocode, I think about a script like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

bbox="$(get_bbox_selected_area --area)"
create_gif --bbox "$bbox" -o "$USER/mygif.gif"
```

I'd need a tool for selecting the area where I want my gif to be created and a different tool for creating the gif in the selected area. Is it possible to do?

---

Observation: I wouldn't mind having to create a different script for killing this process just so the gif stops being created if necessary. In the end, I'll use these scripts as shortcuts just so I can use them at any time. My question is more about how to select a part of my screen and start creating gifs from the command line.

Comment: The recently released GNOME 42's integrated screenshot tool can do recordings now, but I guess that will only be available to Ubuntu users a release or two from now.

Comment: Try `flameshot`. It's in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: @muru I could be wrong... ahem ahem... but I think that Gnome 42 will be in Ubuntu 22.04 in a couple of weeks.

Comment: @heynnema ah nice, I assumed they wouldn't make that big a change this late

Comment: @heynnema I confess `flameshot` turned out very useful for me today already for taking screenshots with arrows :) ... But it doesn't solve the problem with GIFs apparently. I considered it could give me the coordinates of the retangular area on my screen too, but I don't think it's possible using `flameshot`.

Comment: @raylight Play with it some more. You can save screenshots to the clipboard and then paste them into your favorite app, or save it to your disk. You can change the selected area on the fly. You can annotate areas on the clip. Have fun!